# Request transformation in XQuery with appearing double elements

Tags: proxy, request, transform, xquery, osb

i'm trying to transform a request
my sample has among others the following part:

```
<v13:Notes>
    <v13:Note>
        <v12:IDs>
            <v12:ID>1-12345</v12:ID>
        </v12:IDs>
        <v12:Type>Fixed</v12:Type>
        <v12:Categories>
            <v12:Category listName="Category">Internet</v12:Category>
            <v12:Category listName="SubCategory">Slow Speed</v12:Category>
        </v12:Categories>
        <v12:Content>new comments</v12:Content>
        <v12:AgentID>1-abcdef</v12:AgentID>
    </v13:Note>
    <v13:Note>
        <v12:IDs>
            <v12:ID>1-87654</v12:ID>
        </v12:IDs>
        <v12:Type>Fixed</v12:Type>
        <v12:Categories>
            <v12:Category listName="Category">kjhgf</v12:Category>
            <v12:Category listName="SubCategory">sdfcghj Speed</v12:Category>
        </v12:Categories>
        <v12:Content>new chjhmj,nm</v12:Content>
        <v12:AgentID>1-ilkol</v12:AgentID>
    </v13:Note>
</v13:Notes>
<v13:StatusHistory>
    <v12:StateTransition>
        <v12:ReasonCode>Pending</v12:ReasonCode>
        <v12:SubReasonCode>Pending</v12:SubReasonCode>
        <v12:Description>Incident</v12:Description>
    </v12:StateTransition>
    <v12:StateTransition>
        <v12:ID>1-12345</v12:ID>
        <v12:ReasonCode>fixed</v12:ReasonCode>
        <v12:SubReasonCode>fixed</v12:SubReasonCode>
        <v12:Description>Note</v12:Description>
    </v12:StateTransition>
</v13:StatusHistory>
```

and in my transformed request i have to have the following part:

```
<Interaction>
    <OwnedBy>1-abcdef</OwnedBy>
    <Area>Pending</Area>
    <SubArea>Pending</SubArea>
</Interaction>
<Interaction>
    <OwnedBy>1-ilkol</OwnedBy>
    <Area>fixed</Area>
    <SubArea>fixed</SubArea>
</Interaction>
```

but i can't manage to have this in the desired form..
i use:

```
{
                if($UpdateIncidentVBMRequest/v11:IncidentVBO/v13:Parts/v13:StatusHistory/v12:StateTransition/v12:Description/text() = 'Note') then
                (
                let $Note := $UpdateIncidentVBMRequest/v11:IncidentVBO/v13:Parts/v13:Notes/v13:Note
                return
                for $StateTransition in $UpdateIncidentVBMRequest/v11:IncidentVBO/v13:Parts/v13:StatusHistory/v12:StateTransition
                return
                    (
<Interaction>
                            {
                            for $AgendID in $Note/v12:AgentID
                            return
    <OwnedBy>{ data($AgendID) }</OwnedBy>
                            }
                            {
                            for $ReasonCode in $StateTransition/v12:ReasonCode
                                return
    <Area>{ data($ReasonCode) }</Area>
                            }
                            {
                            for $SubReasonCode in $StateTransition/v12:SubReasonCode
                                return
    <SubArea>{ data($SubReasonCode) }</SubArea>
                            }
                            {
                            for $Category in $UpdateIncidentVBMRequest/v11:IncidentVBO/v13:RelatedIncidents/v13:RelatedIncident/v12:Categories/v12:Category
                                return
    <OwnerGroup>{ data($Category) }</OwnerGroup>
                            }
</Interaction>
                    )
                )
                else()
                }
```

and my transformed request is this one:

```
<Interaction>
    <OwnedBy>1-abcdef</OwnedBy>
    <OwnedBy>1-ilkol</OwnedBy>
    <Area>Pending</Area>
    <SubArea>Pending</SubArea>
</Interaction>
<Interaction>
    <OwnedBy>1-abcdef</OwnedBy>
    <OwnedBy>1-ilkol</OwnedBy>
    <Area>fixed</Area>
    <SubArea>fixed</SubArea>
</Interaction>
```

while when i write:

```
for $StateTransition in $UpdateIncidentVBMRequest/v11:IncidentVBO/v13:Parts/v13:StatusHistory/v12:StateTransition
                return

                    (
<Interaction>
                            {
                            for $Notes in $UpdateIncidentVBMRequest/v11:IncidentVBO/v13:Parts/v13:Notes
                            return
                            (<OwnedBy>{ data($Notes/v13:Note/v12:AgentID) }</OwnedBy>)
                            }
```

i come up with the following one:

```
<Interaction>
    <OwnedBy>1-abcdef 1-ilkol</OwnedBy>
    <Area>Pending</Area>
    <SubArea>Pending</SubArea>
</Interaction>
<Interaction>
    <OwnedBy>1-abcdef 1-ilkol</OwnedBy>
    <Area>fixed</Area>
    <SubArea>fixed</SubArea>
</Interaction>
```

so i can't really figure out why the elements appear double in the first place and "concated somehow" in the 2nd example
the other 2 elements (Area, SubArea work as expected)
any help would be much appreceated!!

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think the simplest way to get the desired answer is:

```
for $i in 1 to count(v13:Notes)
return
  <Interaction>
    <OwnedBy>{v13Note[$i]/v12:AgentID/data()}</OwnedBy>
    <Area>{v13:StatusHistory[$i]/v12:StateTransition/v12:ReasonCode/data()}</Area>
    <SubArea>{v13:StatusHistory[$i]/v12:StateTransition/v12:SubReasonCode/data()}</SubArea>
  </Interaction>
```

I may have missed something in your desired logic here, but reverse-engineering your requirements from non-working code isn't easy.

Secondly, the reason your code isn't producing the wanted result is that you write one `<OwnedBy>` element for each element in `$Note/v12:AgentID`, and `$Note` is bound to a sequence containing two `v12:Note` elements; therefore you write two `<OwnedBy>` elements within each `<Interaction>`